# how to sort this vector including pairs

Tags: c++, vector

I want to sort in ascending order according to the first element of the inner pair, i.e. `a` in this case. But its not at all sorting. I am not sure if my function `func` logic is correct.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

bool func(const pair<int,pair<int,int> >&i , const pair<int,pair<int,int> >&j )
{
  i.second.first < j.second.first ;
}


int main()
{
  vector<pair<int,pair<int,int> > > v;
  pair<int,int> pi;
  pair<int,pair<int,int> > po;
  int n,a,b,c,i;

  cin>>n;
  while(n--)
  {
    cin>>a>>b>>c;
    pi=make_pair(a,b);
    po=make_pair(c,pi);
    v.push_back(po);
  }

  cout<<endl;
  for(i=0;i<v.size();i++)
  {
    cout<<v[i].second.first<<" "<<v[i].second.second<<" "<<v[i].first<<endl;
  }
  sort(v.begin(),v.end(),func);
  cout<<endl;
  for(i=0;i<v.size();i++)
  {
    cout<<v[i].second.first<<" "<<v[i].second.second<<" "<<v[i].first<<endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: DR; code but, you just use `std::sort` with your vector, `std::pair`s are lexicographically compared so you'll get your desired behaviour.

Comment: If you'd paid attention to compiler warnings you'd have noticed it saying your `func` function is supposed to return `bool`, but doesn't return anything (i.e. you're missing a `return` statement). Also, `func`, once you add `return`, sorts in descending order.

Comment: @101010 He doesn't want lexicographical ordering of the `pair`s - *I want to sort in acending order according to the first element of the inner pair*

Comment: Further to check for correct logic, you create a number of test cases with different inputs and check if the functions output is as expected.

Comment: @Praetorian thanks for the point I admit I didn't read the body of the question.

Comment: yup. i forgot return func . now its working. thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the return statement in the function

```
bool func(const pair<int,pair<int,int> >&i , const pair<int,pair<int,int> >&j )
{
  i.second.first < j.second.first ;
 }
```

Write instead

```
bool func(const pair<int,pair<int,int> >&i , const pair<int,pair<int,int> >&j )
{
  return i.second.first < j.second.first ;
 }
```

Also you should include header `<utility>` where class `std::pair` is defined

```
#include <utility>
```